# Manipulating textfield values in an iPhone app

Tags: cocoa-touch

How do I manipulate textfield variables within an iPhone app?  I want to have three text fields, formatted to numbers only, and be able to manipulate the data when I press different buttons.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UITextField objects have a "text" property of type NSString that can be read and written.  Keep a reference to the text fields, and when a button is pressed, update the field's text property with a new NSString to change its contents.  If the text fields are not directly editable by the user, you may want to use UILabel instead, which is basically just a non-editable text field (and which also has a read/write "text" property).

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to read about the `NSNumberFormatter` class that allows you to format the input into whatever way is relevant to your application (currency values, floats, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of editing certain text fields, you could disable the user interaction until a button is pressed.